# How to index a family of functions with two indices?

Tags: notation

Let $A$, $B$, $X$ and $Y$ be arbitrary sets with arbitrary elements $a\in A$, $b\in B$, $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$. I am trying to construct a family of functions $f:X\to Y$ indexed by $A$ and $B$ at the same time.

My question is simple: **should I write $(f_a^b)_{a\in A}^{b\in B}$ or $(f_{(a,b)})_{(a,b)\in A\times B}$?** If there are better alternatives than these two options, feel free to let me know.

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: I like to keep the notation uncluttered. I'd write $f_{a,b}$, and note somewhere nearby that $a$ runs through $A$, and $b$ runs through $B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's up to you how to notate the functions. I would just write $f_{a,b}$ for $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. The collection of all such functions would be notated
$$\{f_{a,b}\mid a\in A,b\in B\}.$$
If you wanted to be more formal, you could just define $f$ to be a single function $A\times B\times X\to Y$. The relationship between the two would be $f(a,b,x)=f_{a,b}(x)$.